# Java client has trouble to read big responses from wcf rest service

Tags: java, android, httpwebrequest, wcf

I am trying to consume a rest WCF service using java client on android 2.1.
It works perfectly on small responses. When i tried to push a little further by getting 1000+ char response reader.read(buffer) failed to read all the characters. This caused the last line of the script to return: JsonException unterminated string at character 8193 "{plate,...

My android device starts to get this error before the emulator android stars to get it (character 1194 instead of 8193). Anyone knows how get the full message?

Client Code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/GetPlates");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
reader.read(buffer);
stream.close();         
JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
```

Server Config:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="big_webHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4097152" maxBufferSize="4097152" maxBufferPoolSize="4097152">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="4097152" maxArrayLength="4097152" maxBytesPerRead="4097152" maxNameTableCharCount="4097152" maxDepth="4097152"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
reader.read(buffer);
stream.close();
```

do this:

```
String jsonText = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```